# Warning: Could not find file C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\javadb\lib\derbyclient.jar to copy. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello i am developing a web application with struts 1.x and Hibernate in Net beans IDES.
I developed four apps.two apps are running on Tomcat server,but when i tried to run another one ,I am getting 
"Warning: Could not find file C:\Program Files\glass fish-3.0.1\java db\lib\derbyclient.jar to copy.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
  i am not using Glashfish server any way.
how to resolve it ? please help any one

Answer (score 0):

Check the .classpath file in your project or the project build path. It will be referring to this jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 3 years old, but for future reference or to anyone who might need it:

You need to go to the project settings, choose the Libraries tab, and from there you need to specify the path to the `derbyclient.jar` file. If you don't know where you have installed it, you can download and install it [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html).